# Числа вместо слов

Tags: android, java

В TextView хочу написать слово

```
    insInfo.setText(R.string.ins_info + " " + R.string.in);
```

в итоге выдает цифры вместо слов  2131427369 а должно выйти предложение. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело в том, что есть 2 разных метода

```
setText(int resourceId);  
setText(CharSequence text);
```

Так вот, `R.string.ins_info` - это id ресурса, который содержит строку. этот id имеет тип `int`.  
А второй метод принимает [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) - интерфейс, который как раз и реализует класс `String`.  
Так вот, когда вы вызываете

```
insInfo.setText(R.string.ins_info + " " + R.string.in);
```

вызывается второй метод.  
Почему? Потому, что выражение вида `R.string.ins_info + " " + R.string.in` невозможно привести к типу `int`, но можно привести к `String`. Собственно, его и приводить ненадо, оно как раз и имеет тип `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы не понимаете как работает `setText(R.string.ins_info)` - по сути это то же самое что и вызов: `setText(context.getString(R.string.ins_info))`, как только вы напишете:

```
 setText(R.string.ins_info+"") //вы немедленно получите тарабарщину
```

Попробуйте теперь догадаться как надо написать ваш код чтобы все заработало.

Comment: я понял я присваиваю номер R.String, сейчас работает  

    getString(R.string.ins);